# Slow image loading on Cordova app, Jquery, AngularJS, Ionic

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, performance, cordova

I have a Cordova app (which uses Ionic, AngularJS, and JQuery for a few misc plugins).

When running in a browser or iOS everything is normal speed for image loading and works fine.

On Android the images take horribly long, over a minute per image.[image: Slow image loads]

At the same time I tested on my browser (same wifi) and received the below, fast and normal speeds of under a second per picture.[image]

Is this because jquery is the initiator of the call? How can I change that? The images are referenced via ng-src as below

```
<img ng-src="{{person.profilePictureURL}}">
```

Comment: Found a solution? im also facing the same issue...

Comment: Sorry @user3316017 I don't recall how this went down :-\

Comment: sorry for bumping it up but any of you guys found and can remember whats causing the problems? I have the same problem and am suspecting lack of ram :'( @KishanB